# How to move Lightning Pages from One environment to another

Tags: deployment

how to move Lightning Pages from one environment to another environment using ant

[image]

How to move these user data record pages & settings to another environment.

Comment: looks like an ootb record detail component, what is displayed in that component is normally set throguh page layouts assigned at a profile level. It's unclear what you are asking exatly.

Comment: I need to drag and drop few elements in related list. after adding that how can I move it

Comment: for related list changes, you need to go to the layouts. Go to Related tab here, click on related lists component (in preview) then in right panel you can see the layouts! For migrating lightning page via ant, you can check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Record Pages, and all other Lightning Pages, can be deployed between environments using Change Sets or using any Metadata API tool, such as Ant, Workbench, or an IDE.

The `<types>` entry that you would include in your `package.xml` is [`FlexiPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>New Opportunity Page Package</fullName>
    <description>Contains an opportunity page with a rich text component that has rules assigned</description>
    <types>
        <members>New_Opportunity_Page</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

More important than the component itself, though, is its dependencies. You must ensure that you all of the related entities, such as custom Lightning components, and any Page Layouts expected to be rendered by Record Detail components are also deployed or already present in the target org.